# Upload File To Amazon S3 Using Java Not Working

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am newbie and recently started working on amazon s3 services.

I have create a java maven project and using Java 1.8 and aws-java-sdk version 1.11.6 version in my sample program

Below is source code for the same and it executes successfully.

It returns version id as output of the program.

```
    System.out.println("Started the program to create the bucket....");
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(CloudMigrationConstants.AWS_ACCOUNT_KEY, CloudMigrationConstants.AWS_ACCOUNT_SECRET_KEY);

    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCreds);
    String uploadFileName="G:\\Ebooks\\chap1.doc";
    String bucketName="jinesh1522421795620";
    String keyName="test/";

    System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");
    File file = new File(uploadFileName);
    PutObjectResult putObjectResult=s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(
                                         bucketName, keyName, file));

System.out.println("Version id :" + putObjectResult.getVersionId());

System.out.println("Finished the program to create the bucket....");
```

But when I try to see the files using s3browser or amazon console I do not see the files are listed inside the bucket.

Can you please let me know what is wrong with My Java program?

Comment: why downvoted the question? Please specify reason

Answer (score 0):

I think I misunderstood the concept. We have to specify the name of the file to store while specifying the key. In above program what I missed was specifying the name of the file along with name of the folder hence I was not able to see the file.

```
File file = new File(uploadFileName);
PutObjectResult putObjectResult=s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(
                                         bucketName, keyName+"/chap1.doc", file));
```